# What document should i give under 'documents showing where you live' for UK visa from India, if i dont have tenancy agreements, deeds etc?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I live with my uncle and aunt in a rented house but the rent agreement is not in my name. Although this address is the address in my passport, i am not sure what document should i give for 'documents showing where you live' since i don't have a mortgage or property deed. Please help. Can i just give a legal affidavit of residence?

Comment: IMHO, although a ‘Home address’ section is included in the document checklist accompanying a visitor visa application, it is not a mandatory requirement to prove your address. What is required is confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport. There is no mention of proof of address being needed in https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: Do you have any mail sent to your current address? Credit card bills, bank statements, government correspondence of any kind showing your address?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yup all my bank accounts are registered to that address